# Trouble using class weight with categorical cross Entropy

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras to perform pixel-wise multiclass classification in many 256x256 2D images. Because of the amount of data and classes I have (32), I'm using an image generator to feed data into network during training. The main purpose of the generator is to one-hot encode my ground truth which ends up being 256x256x32 in size (if I try to one-hot encode beforehand I get an OOM error).

However, when I try to use the class_weight setting when fitting my model, I get an error saying it doesn't support 3+ dimensional targets. I've already flattened my images, so the output is size (batch size, 65536, 32). I don't get how I'm supposed to make them 2D. I can't use the sample_weight setting because model.fit_generator doesn't have that setting.

Here's the code for my data generator.

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):
# Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 256, 256, 1))
batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,256*256,32))
while True:
    for i in range(batch_size):
        # choose random index in features
        #index= random.choice(len(features),1)
        index=i
        batch_features[i] = features[index]
        batch_labels[i] = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels[index],num_classes=32)
    yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use sample weights in your generator(custom) according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator)

generator: A generator or an instance of Sequence (keras.utils.Sequence) object in order to avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing. The output of the generator must be either

```
a tuple (inputs, targets)
a tuple (inputs, targets, sample_weights).
```